# For each challenge a solution OR To each Challenge its solution

Tags: prepositions, to-for

I'm wondering which of the following is actually correct:
- For each challenge a solution 
- To each Challenge its solution

I need it this way because it's for a title. And I need it short and catchy.

Even if I make a complete sentence I get confused. 
'There's a solution to/for each challenge'
I'd say 'for'.

What do you think?

Comment: Challenge Brings Solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: "Every challenge has its solution"

Comment: Thanks for your help Peterflynn.
Indeed, it works perfectly.

However, I want to make a short and catchy sentence with no verb.
Plus, it's for my own grammar improvement. 

So, should I use For or To?

Plus, I'm now wondering if 'each' is correct. Maybe 'every' is better as in A Solution for Every Challenge